# Weak topologies and direct product

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

In several places I have seen the embeddings of spaces with weak topology into direct products. More precisely, if $X$ is a Banach space and $X'$ is it's dual, then $X$ with weak topology can be embedded into the direct product of copies of $\mathbb{R}$, indexed by elements of $X'$ and vice versa, $X'$ with *-weak topology can be embedded into the direct product of $\mathbb R$'s, indexed by elements of $X$ (please correct me if I am wrong).

However such embeddings seem to ignore linearity. So my question is:

can we use as an indexing set not the whole space, but only (for example) it's linear basis?
or a total (maximal linearly-independent, dense) subset ?

Comment: Yes, I think I was a little misleading. I remember seeing somewhere $f\in X (X')$, not just unit ball. But this is not the point. The question is: is it necessary to have and $f_1+f_2$ term in that product, when we have $f_1$ and $f_2$ terms? Same for $const*f$.

Comment: What I was actually saying is about the embedding $x\to(f(x))_{f\in B_{X'}}$: what is the use of $((f_1+f_2)(x))_{f_1+f_2}$ if we know $(f_1(x))_{f_1}$ and $(f_2(x))_{f_2}$? Can we reduce the index set only to a linear basis or a total subset?